# Override kerberos service principal when using curl with negotiate

Tags: curl, kerberos

I have a server ("server.example.com") that negotiates with an IdP ("sso.idp.com") on my behalf to obtain a SAML assertion. When using `curl` with negotiate, the domain name in the service principal is "server.example.com" by default, e.g. HTTP/server.example.com@MYREALM.COM.

I'm wondering if it's possible to override the domain name used in the service principal. Basically, something similar to the Python package `requests-kerberos`' [hostname override](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos#hostname-override), or Node package `kerberos`' "service" param in [initalizeClient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos#initializeclientservice-options-callback). I can't seem to find an equivalent option for `curl`, and was wondering if there is one? I've found the [service name option](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SERVICE_NAME.html) which appears to set the service type (e.g. HTTP), but nothing that sets the domain name.

Basically:

```sh
curl -v --negotiate -u : server.example.com
```

creates a service principal of HTTP/server.example.com@MYREALM.COM. But, I'm looking for something like:

```sh
curl -v --negotiate -u : server.example.com --service HTTP/sso.idp.com
```

that would create a service principal of HTTP/sso.idp.com@MYREALM.COM. I just want to override the domain name in the service principal so I can generate an Authorization header to negotiate with "sso.idp.com".

Comment: Looks like you want to use a VIP or a Load Balancer...? Define a DNS alias on a dedicated IP, with reverse lookup, and use the alias in the URL. That's what is done in the Hadoop ecosystem. Works transparently with any client.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange way to implement Kerberos delegation.

Curl lets you achieve this in the opposite way: use `--connect-to` to override the actual server address.

```
curl -u: --negotiate --connect-to "sso.idp.com:443:server.example.com:443" https://sso.idp.com
```

Comment: IMHO that's not "delegation" in the Kerberos sense, it's more about "network virtualization"... Sthg good'old Kerberos was not designed for.